# javafx parameters in command prompt gives null values

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8

Goodevening everyone,

This might be a silly question but I seem to struggle finding an answer to it. I've created a simple JavaFX8 program that should be able to read command line arguments.

Let me illustrate:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       
    Map parameters = getParameters().getNamed();

    System.out.println("parameter is " + parameters.get("myKey"));

    ...
}
```

When I define a parameter named *myKey* in NetBeans with value **abc**,

[image: netbeans_parameters]

it results in the following output when I run my application from the IDE:

```
parameter is abc
```

However, if I run it from the command prompt as following:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar myKey=abc
```

it returns value **null**, which means the parameters isn't forwarded to the JavaFX application:

```
parameter is null
```

Why is this? It's the first time I'm working with parameters so apologies if the answer is really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use the following syntax when calling from command-line:

`java -jar JavaHelp.jar --p1=hello --p2=world`

getNamed only returns something if parameter is annotated with **--** (I think this equals 'NAMED')

Try it with this program and you can see:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
        System.out.println(getParameters().getRaw().toString());
        getParameters().getNamed().forEach((name, string) -> {
            System.out.println("Parameter[" + name + "]=" + string);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane() {{
            getChildren().add(new Button("B"));
        }}));
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Parameter[p1]=hello
Parameter[p2]=world
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `--` before each argument.  So the command you need is:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar --myKey=abc
```